# Python list reference and just another copy

Tags: python, list, reference

I wish to bring that last k elements of 'nums' array to the first. Like, Input:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3
```

Output:

```
[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
```

I have the following code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def rotate(self, nums, k):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        n = len(nums)
        k = k % n
        nums[:] = nums[n-k:] + nums[:n-k]
```

This works perfectly fine i.e. brings the last k elements to the beginning and nums shows [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]. But once I type the following `nums = nums[n-k:] + nums[:n-k]`, it shows the resultant nums array as being the same original [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].

My question is, why is the change in output taking place? On googling and upon reding certain other threads in this forum pertaining to 'List Referencing and copying', I could realize that `nums =`  is something about list referencing but `nums[:]` is like a mere copy of the list. But having said thiat, why is this change in output taking place? What's happening inside both the commands?

Seems like `nums` and `nums[:]` aren't yet clear to me. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Explanation

##### nums = nums[n-k:] + nums[:n-k]

The assignment `nums = nums[n-k:] + nums[:n-k]` would be equivalent to create a new list in memory (with the elements reversed), and changing the pointer `nums` to point to that new list. But since the variable `nums` that you change is local to the function, this change does not affect to the external one passed as parameter. Check follow diagram for better understanding:

[image: 1]

---

##### nums[:] = nums[n-k:] + nums[:n-k]

The assignment `nums[:] = nums[n-k:] + nums[:n-k]` would be equivalent to write a new reversed list at the same address pointed by `nums`, because the slice allows to replace part of a list with new contents.

[image: 2]

In this case you are not changing the variable `nums`, but the data pointed by it.

**Example Code:**

```
def rotate(nums, k):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type k: int
    :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
    """
    n = len(nums)
    k = k % n
    # in function
    # nums[:] = nums[n-k:] + nums[:n-k]
    nums = nums[n-k:] + nums[:n-k]

# in scope
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
k = 3
rotate(nums, k)
print(nums)
```

Comment: Note that none of this would matter if you were passing k to the function and return n, which would be more normal (unless you were modifying `self.nums` on a class)

Comment: @2e0byo Thank you so much for the suggestion. Unfortunately I was provided a hardcoded method template with no return type. Still, I wanted to ask how would it be different if I am returning n which is just a number(length of nums)? Why wouldn't these staffs be necessary then?

Comment: @Sabil My heartfelt thanks for such a comprehensive reply. One more question, what is meant by 'in-scope' of a variable? What's the difference between 'in-function' and 'in-scope' of a variable?

Comment: Oops, I meant returning *nums*.  In that case the fact that you shadow the out-of-scope nums with a local nums would be irrelevant (if possibly slightly less performant).  +1 to @sabil for the diagrams btw

Comment: I meant by `in scope` is outside of the function call. If you print `nums` inside the function then you can see your desire output for both cases. @QUEEN

Comment: @Sabil I have accepted your answer and have already upvoted it before :)

Answer (score 1):

In Python List Slicing,

> To Get all the Items After a Specific Position use `nums[pos:]` #( pos for position ) and
> To Get all the Items Before a Specific Position use `nums[:pos]`

Slicing is a command describing how to display data from the original list and it's a Shallow copy operation. Shallow copies don’t actually copy each element’s value. Instead, they reference the memory location of each of the values from List `nums`
[image]

> Here print(nums[:]) returns all elements of the list like print(nums)but when assigned to a slicing operation :
>
> > `nums=nums[len(nums)-k%len(nums):]+nums[:len(nums)-k%len(nums)]`
> > or
> > `nums= nums[n-k:] + nums[:n-k]`Here assigning that to {nums} has no effect on the previous value of the variable.

> > But `nums[:]=nums[len(nums)-k%len(nums):]+nums[:len(nums)-k%len(nums)]`
> > or
> > `nums[:]= nums[n-k:] + nums[:n-k]`
> > here assigning it to nums[:] inserts it into the existing list, replacing all of the previous elements.

Solution for Problem -> to bring that last k elements of 'nums' array to the first:

```
def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int):

     nums[:]=nums[len(nums)-k%len(nums):]+nums[:len(nums)-k%len(nums)]
```